# Напишите способ файлов переопределения в ОС Linux

Tags: linux, override

Программе нужны файлы, но перемещать в директорию программе запрашиваемую нельзя. Нужно запустить программу так, у программы написать конфиг файла_путь_запрашиваемый=файла_путь_переопределённый
По схожести с LD_LIBRARY или PATH, но другое.

Comment: Эм, просто сделать переход в нужный каталог перед запуском программы?

Comment: `$ ln -s файл1 файл2`

Comment: Почти ничего не понятно. Вы хотите использовать environmen `CONF_PATH=path1:path2:...:path_n` и читать файл конфига, который находится в одном из этих каталогов? (если хотите ответить в комментарии с оповещением конкретного участника, то добавьте в начало комментария @his_nick)

Comment: Одну директорию заменить на другую, без символичесвких ссылок. Кроме того, программы умеют определять что ссылки символические, и не запускаться.